# Copying a string to a struct member

Tags: c

I can't figure out how to copy a string from `inputString` to `newNode->data`.

My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;
```

And the function in questions looks like this:

```
node* addToTree(char inputString[]) {
    node *newNode;

    if ((newNode = malloc(sizeof(node*))) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not allocate memory");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((newNode->data = malloc(strlen(inputString) + 1)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not allocate memory");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* This line of code doesn't seem to copy anything to newNode->data. 
       This is the way I believe should work, however I don't understand what the 
       problem with it is. I have tried strlcpy and strncpy as well. */
    strcpy(newNode->data, inputString);


    /* The line below here seems to work when I print the value
       within the function, but some of the values are garbage when
       I try to use them later on in the program. */
    newNode->data = inputString;


    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    printf("Input string: %s\n", inputString);
    printf("New node data: %s\n", newNode->data);

    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: `newnode = malloc(sizeof(node*))` ==> `newnode = malloc(sizeof (node))` or, better, `newnode = malloc(sizeof *newNode)`

Comment: If you have, just use `strdup` to merge `malloc + strcpy` into one statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sizeof(node*)` does not represent the size you need.

```
newnode = malloc(sizeof(node*))    // wrong
newnode = malloc(sizeof (node))    // correct
newnode = malloc(sizeof *newNode)  // better
```

---

Why is `sizeof *newNode` better?

Because it prevents accidental forgetting to update the code in **two** places if the type changes

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
struct nodeEx {
    char *data;
    size_t len;
    struct nodeEx *next;
    struct nodeEx *prev;
};

struct nodeEx *newnode = malloc(sizeof (struct node)); // wrong
struct nodeEx *newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);      // correct
```

Comment: I think you meant you write new*N*ode?

Comment: Why is using `sizeof *newNode` better than `sizeof (node)`? Wouldn't they always be the same size?

Comment: @Jake because the *newNode has always the the correct type. Imagine you change the type of a variable then you would have to change the sizeof for the allocation too. In this case it is not that relevant but is considered a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The below line does not allocate the required amount of memory, it allocates memory equal to the size of a **pointer to** `node`.

```
if ((newNode = malloc(sizeof(node*))) == NULL)
```

So your `strcpy` fails because there is no memory to copy into.

Change the above to:

```
if ((newNode = malloc(sizeof(node))) == NULL)
```

What happens after you do the following is **undefined behavior** because the memory representing `inputString` can be overwritten, and that is why you get garbage values later on.

```
newNode->data = inputString;
```

You can see the top answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794) for additional information.

Comment: @pmg: Yes. I was thinking of this scenario. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794

Answer (score 0):

```
newNode->data = inputString;
```

is incorrect, it overrides the previously `malloc`ed memory.

```
if ((newNode->data = malloc(strlen(inputString) + 1)) == NULL) {
    printf("Error: could not allocate memory");
    exit(-1);
}
strcpy(newNode->data, inputString);
```

is enough to allocate memory and copy the string into it.